# My iframe videos works fine on desktop, but will not resize for mobile devices. How can I fix this?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, iframe, youtube

I have a video on my webpage which plays a YouTube video. On desktop this works completely fine, however, when I inspect this on mobile devices, even after using media queries, the iframe does not resize to fit to mobile devices. How can I get my iframe's to scale down correctly as it is viewed from device to device?

So far, I have this

```
<div class="container-fluid text-justify bg-2" id = "video-container">
  <h2 class = "text-center">Sample Text</h2>
  <p>Some more sample text <br>
  Another line of Sample text </p>

  <div id = "video">
    <iframe  width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/sIP4Gymk1nE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> 
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/U4TUt2ukzyE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XS4S2O8UXqE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

 </div>
</div>
```

Alongside this, I also have CSS:

```
#video iframe{padding: 15px;}
@media all and (max-width: 768px){

 #video-container > #video > iframe{
    padding: 15px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;

}}
```

Finally, this is what is currently looks like on a mobile device when trying it where the video has overspilled out of the div. 
[image]

How can this be solved? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

**HTML**

```
 <div class="container-fluid text-justify bg-2" id = "video-container">
    <h2 class = "text-center">Sample Text</h2>
    <p>Some more sample text <br>
        Another line of Sample text </p>

    <div class="video">
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/sIP4Gymk1nE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class = "video">
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/U4TUt2ukzyE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class = "video">
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XS4S2O8UXqE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
        #video-container {
            max-width: 560px;
        }
        .video {
            position:relative;
            padding-bottom:56.25%;
            padding-top:30px;
            height:0;
            overflow:hidden;
        }
        .video iframe {
            position:absolute;
            top:0;
            left:0;
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
        }
```

It worked for me. Good luck!

Comment: Does that mean I will no longer need to bother with the media queries then?

Comment: yes, you don't need. it will be width = 100% container width

Comment: Perfect! this worked for my site, thank you very much!